# MAMP can't incresse phpmyadmin upload limit

Tags: upload, phpmyadmin, filesize, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP 3.0.3 and have phpmyadmin 4.1.9 installed. I have changed the php.ini files in all locations within: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.X/conf` to all have:

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 256M
```

When I restart the server the limit still remains at 32M. Even in MAMPs webstart page it says 32M.

I've updated both reported php.ini files that its loading too:

**Configuration File (php.ini) Path:** `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/conf`

**Loaded Configuration File:** `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini`

Nothing's working.

Answer (score 1):

The phpMyAdmin application has a configuration file that overwrites the PHP settings. Check your `apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf`.

There you will find these lines:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

Just increase them and the UX should allow you to upload bigger files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for version 4.x MAMP Pro. The file in described folder doesn't exist in the MAMP folder but a php.ini too and at the end it is overwritten every time you run Server again.
So in MAMP Pro you can choose on the left "PHP" and than on top next to the selected PHP-Version click the arrow. It opens the standard configuration in an editor. Change your settings close and then you will be asked to save.